# Do footnotes take margin space?

Tags: footnotes

For a project I need the margin at minimum 2cm. I have added footnotes and am wondering if this makes the bottom of the page less than 2cm. It looks the same but I am just looking for clarification. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Footnotes are always typeset inside the text block.

Comment: So does that mean I don't have to worry about going less than the 2cm limit?

Comment: @Eduardo: Yes. If you're using [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry), and include a page number in the footer, you can look at options to set the margins with/without them.

Answer (score 5):

Footnotes are part of the text block, so they will remain above the lower margin. The text block will never be higher than `\textheight`. The space for running text will be decreased as needed to make room for the footnotes.

The text block height can be increased or decreased if `\enlargethispage` is issued in the page, but footnotes will respect the (modified) height nonetheless.

In limit cases the page *can* be oversized, but a warning

```
Overfull \vbox (xxx.yyyyy pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
```

will appear in the log file. Normal text won't suffer from this problem. Typical candidates for this warning are oversized floats.